# how to add rating bar in Linear Layout Dynamically in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have tried to add rating bar in Linear Layout at dynamically after some textfields. But I'm getting NullPointerException at the line = lL.addView(rating); Can someone help me please how to do this.Thanks in Advance.

Here is my xml file.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnDELETE"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutRatingDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_EmployeeName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="dfkyjrtl"
                android:textColor="#2E1F1F" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_TaskName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="dfkyjrtl"
                android:textColor="#2E1F1F" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_TaskDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="dfkyjrtl"
                android:textColor="#2E1F1F" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_TaskRate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="dfkyjrtl"
                android:textColor="#2E1F1F" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>




Hare is my Activity code.

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task_details);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        str_IntentName = intent.getExtras().getString("EMP_NAME");
        str_IntentTaskName = intent.getExtras().getString("TASK_NAME");
        str_IntentDate = intent.getExtras().getString("TASK_DATE");
        str_IntentRate = intent.getExtras().getString("TASK_RATE");

        numStar = Integer.valueOf(str_IntentRate);
        Log.e("integer numStar "," = " + numStar);

        lL = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRatingDetails);


        tvEmpName.setText(str_IntentName);
        tvTaskName.setText(str_IntentTaskName);
        tvDate.setText(str_IntentDate);
        tvRate.setText(str_IntentRate);
        Create_RatingBar();



    }

    private void Create_RatingBar() 
    {
        stepSize = (float) 0.5;
        rating = new RatingBar(Task_Details.this);
        rating.setNumStars(numStar);
        rating.setStepSize(stepSize);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        param.topMargin = 500;
        rating.setLayoutParams(param);
        lL.addView(rating);
    }
```

Comment: I'm gonna gues `lL` is null

Comment: Try to post your activity whole code instead just snippet.

Comment: Where are you initializing lL, put complete code here, as LordRaydenMK said 100% IL is null !!

Answer (score 0):

In order to add it to the LinearLayout from your xml you need to get a "reference" to this LinearLayout in your code. For that you need to ad **id** it in xml and get an element using this **id** in your code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Some other code for other views
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRatingDetails);
    setupRatingBar(container)
}

private void setupRatingBar(ViewGroup ratingBarContainer){
    RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(Task_Details.this);
    //All methods you need to initialize the rating bar
    //including setNumStars(), setStepSize() and layout params

    ratingBarContainer.addView(ratingBar);
}
```

Also use more explanatory names. "lL" will cause you headache in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , But i did not get you . Please can you explain hoe to do ?

Comment: I have changes in the code but rating bar not showing.

Comment: Yah i'm also changing llike this LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRatingDetails);
container.addView(ratingView); in my code. Then also it is not viewed rating bar.

Comment: It is hard to spot an error without seeing the code. There may be many reason why the view is not shown. My recommendation would be to use the simplest possible layout to debug what your doing wrong. Create an activity layout consisting only of LinearLayout and try to add rating bar to it. Once it is done you can transfer your code to the real activity.